# Delete Specific rows in Excel

Tags: excel, delete-row, vba

I want to create a for loop to check all of the rows in a sheet that I have and want this code to be able to delete rows if they contain a specified content in certain columns (i.e. if column K contains "June" delete the row.  Is there a way to code this?

*Edit
I have the code working to search for criteria in one column, but now I need it to search and delete rows based on the data in two columns.  i.e. If the data in column K matches cell AJ1 (already have) and the data in column J matches AK1, then delete these rows.

The code I have is this:

Sub DeleteRows()

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Dim rFind As Range
Dim rDelete As Range
Dim strSearch As String
Dim iLookAt As Long
Dim bMatchCase As Boolean

strSearch = Range("AJ1")


iLookAt = xlWhole
bMatchCase = False

Set rDelete = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheet1.Columns("K:K")

    Set rFind = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=iLookAt, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=bMatchCase)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        Do
            Set rDelete = rFind
            Set rFind = .FindPrevious(rFind)
            If rFind.Address = rDelete.Address Then Set rFind = Nothing
            rDelete.EntireRow.Delete
        Loop While Not rFind Is Nothing
    End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  Try to write it, then post back *with your code* and describe any problem you run into.  Or try searching here for the many similar questions already asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+delete+rows

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid looping over cells if possible in Excel VBA.  Looping over cells is [slow and inefficient](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA1/excelvba1lesson11.htm).  It may not matter given the scope of your program, but it is something to be considered.  If you are new to VBA programming, it's especially important to pick up good habits early on.

Here is a solution using the `Range.Find` method ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx)) to gather the range of rows to delete, and then delete them all in one statement.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim rngResults As Range, rngToDelete As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange 'Adjust to your particular worksheet

        Set rngResults = .Cells.Find(What:="June") 'Adjust what you want it to find
        If Not rngResults Is Nothing Then

            Set rngToDelete = rngResults

            strFirstAddress = rngResults.Address

            Set rngResults = .FindNext(After:=rngResults)

            Do Until rngResults.Address = strFirstAddress
                Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngResults)
                Set rngResults = .FindNext(After:=rngResults)
            Loop

        End If

    End With

    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete

    Set rngResults = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If I want what is deleted to be referenced to a cell (June is in cell AJ1) and I plug this in to the code, it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  If you want rows containing "June" to be deleted on the sheet "Sheet1" this _should_ do it (I tested it and it seemed to work fine).  I don't exactly know what you mean by "if I want what is deleted to be referenced to a cell".  You want to search by cell reference instead of value?  It's possible we need to add the `lookin:=xlValues` to the `.Cells.Find(What:="June")`

Comment: Sorry, poor wording. Instead of "June," I want the macro to delete the rows when a cell contains the value in cell AJ1.

Comment: You should be able to change `.Cells.Find(What:="June")` to `.Cells.Find(What:="AJ1", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas)`.  This will search the formulas of the cell and look for any reference to AJ1, if there is a reference to AJ1 that row will be flagged for deletion.  I am assuming here that you are using a formula and somehow referencing cell AJ1 to get that value.

Answer (score 0):

This will process rows **2** thru **4000,** adjust to suit your needs:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim K As Range, rKill As Range
    Set K = Range("K2:K4000")
    Set rKill = Nothing
    For Each r In K
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, "June") > 0 Then
            If rKill Is Nothing Then
                Set rKill = r
            Else
                Set rKill = Union(r, rKill)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not rKill Is Nothing Then
        rKill.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```